# Function return pointers

Tags: c++

Suppose our code is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler needs to allocate memmory for foo()'s return adress on the stack.
How much memory does it allocate?Is it based on the functions return type?

Comment: It is implementation defined but is roughly a function of the return type, all function arguments, and local variables within that function.

Comment: The "return address", ie the caller's memory address that flow returns to when `foo()` exits, is just that - an address. So it is `sizeof(void*)` in size, 4 bytes for 32bit, 8 bytes for 64bit . The "return value", on the other hand, is a whole other matter. How that is allocated depends on a lot of factors - the type, whether it is passed by value or reference/pointer, NRVO, target platform, compiler implementation, etc

Comment: You should explore the assy code generated at godbolt.org for different CPUs/OSes/Compilers to understand this area. It will come in useful as you learn more about C++